# Higher GRE Quantitative score?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, gre

Lately, I have scored 165 in Quantitative Reasoning part of the GRE. The schools I consider applying requires scores that fall above the 90th percentile. with 165 Quant score, I am just at the 90th percentile. (just for a background, very good GPA (almost in %1 of my cohort), good academic references, a related job experience etc.)

There is no time to retake it, as the funding deadlines for graduate schools are approaching and I need to use this score to be evaluated for scholarships. 
If I have another GRE test immediately, the results will only be helpful for being assessed without scholarships as the funding deadline will be already passed at that time.

However, I wonder what is the difference between a 165 Quant score or 167-68 band? The graduate schools need it from different nationalities than they are, especially to compare candidates. However, do you think higher GPA, good recommendation letters are as crucial as GRE?

I would be quite sad if I am not admitted to the schools I want just because of this low Quant score. Is it really to low?

Btw: department: Economics.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a bit of a search you will learn that the GRE has little predictive value for success in graduate study. Given that, I doubt that a difference of five points has any significance at all.

But how a GRE is *interpreted* by a specific admissions system is completely up to them, so, again, no prediction can be made here.

Focus your application on other things. In general, a lot of things are likely to be considered. They will be looking for predictors of success. Give them that.

---

Search: predictive value of GRE